# Multiple && (and) and || (or) in a for loop. Which one is checked?

Tags: java

I have a for loop with multiple conditions like that:

```
for(int i = 4; i < 100 && (i-1)%6 == 0 || (i+1)%6 == 0; i++) {
    //do something
}
```

Now, how does Java handle the conditions? Is it if both and conditions are correct or the other one **or** is my for loop doing something when the first and one of the last conditions are true? And should i use parenthesis to clarify what i want it to do?

I wanted to avoid to many if statements in my for loop, or am i obliged to use if statements?

Comment: Your code, as it is, means `(i < 100 && (i-1)%6 == 0) || (i+1)%6 == 0`. Should you add parentheses? Yes.

Comment: Read [this](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/), you may get a full landscape of java operator precedence.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: FYI: The condition can be simplified by much. Actually it is redundant as a whole.

Comment: I'd like to but it's too much to explain it in a *nice* and *readable* way as a comment and sadly the post got already closed, so I can't post it as an answer. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Anyways, @noahkln_ please feel free to post another question with the same statement. And make sure it's about the *simplification* so it's not closed instantly.